# Unity C# - How to check if random moving gameobject is within boundaries

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a random moving gameobject moving in the scene with the attached code. The issue is that although there are boundary colliders with a rigid body, sometimes it passes right through them and falls.

How can I limit it that once it bumps into those colliders it does a 189 rotation and continues moving randomly?

The terrain width is 50f, the terrain Height is also 50f.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerTrainingMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed;

    private float randomizedSpeed = 0.0f;
    private float nextActionTime = -1.0f;
    private Vector3 targetPosition;
    private Vector3 moveVector;
    private void FixedUpdate() {

        if(speed > 0.0f) {
            Move2(); 
            //Move();
        }
    }

    private void Move2() {

        if(Time.fixedTime >= nextActionTime) {

            // Get a threshold time
            nextActionTime = UnityEngine.Random.Range(50.0f, 200.0f);

            // Pick a random target position
            targetPosition = TrainingArea.ChooseRandomPosition(transform.parent.position, 0f, 270f, 2f, 10f);

             
            // Rotate towards the target position
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetPosition - transform.position, Vector3.up);

            float timeToGetThere = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targetPosition) / randomizedSpeed;
            nextActionTime = Time.fixedTime + timeToGetThere;


            // Get a movement vector
            moveVector = speed * transform.forward;
            //moveVector = speed * new Vector3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        }
        else {

            // Check -X boundary
            if(transform.position.x - 1.0f <= transform.parent.gameObject.transform.position.x) {

                transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                moveVector.x *= -1.0f;
            }

            // Check +X boundary
            if(transform.position.x + 1.0f >= transform.parent.gameObject.transform.position.x + TrainingArea.terrainWidth) {

                transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                moveVector.x *= -1.0f;
            }

            // Check -Z boundary
            if(transform.position.z - 1.0f <= transform.parent.gameObject.transform.position.z) {

                transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
                moveVector.z *= -1.0f;
            }

            // Check +Z boundary
            if(transform.position.z + 1.0f >= transform.parent.gameObject.transform.position.z + TrainingArea.terrainHeight) {

                transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
                moveVector.z *= -1.0f;
            }

            // Move 
            transform.position = transform.position + moveVector * Time.fixedDeltaTime;

            // Update nextActionTime
            nextActionTime--;
        }
    }
}
public static Vector3 RandomPositionOnTerrain(Vector3 origin) {
    //Range(30.0f, terrainWidth - 30.0f);
    float randomX = origin.x + UnityEngine.Random.Range(20.0f, terrainWidth);
    float randomZ = origin.z + UnityEngine.Random.Range(20.0f, terrainHeight);

    return new Vector3(randomX, 30.0f, randomZ);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OnCollisionEnter` to trigger a rotation when the unit bumps into other colliders.

something like this must do it:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
   {
       if(col.gameObject.tag(or name) = "a tag or name"){
          //Do Stuff here
       }
   }
```

Here's the detailed documentation:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html

another workaround is using `NavMesh`. It'll make the movements `UnityEngine.AI` based and pretty smooth but you'll need a whole new script.